# Set active class with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I try to use the following javascript to set active class

```
var url = window.location.pathname,
                    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url == '/' ? window.location.origin + '/?$' : url.replace(/\/$/, '')); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there
                // now grab every link from the navigation
                $('.page-sidebar a').each(function () {
                    // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
                    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
                });
```

The problem is that i need to set it on parent `<li>` element, not the `<a>`

Example of my HTML menu

```
<div class="page-sidebar nav-collapse collapse">
   <ul>
      <li>
          <div class="sidebar-toggler hidden-phone"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="start"> // HERE I NEED TO ADD CLASS ACTIVE
          <a href="/default.aspx">
          <i class="icon-home"></i>
          <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
      </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.closest(`) to find the closest ancestor/parent that matches the desired selector.  This is more flexible and safer than just using the direct parent because it continues to work even if some types of changes are made to the HTML markup (such as an extra layer of markup inserted between target and parent).

```
$(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(this).addClass('active');` to `$(this).parent().addClass('active');`.

Answer (score 1):

To set it on the parent:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use closest():

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
```